# Change time picker mode with Cordova

Tags: cordova, timepicker

I'm using a time input (pure HTML `<input type="time">`) in my app. It's rendered as a *spinner* on most of devices, but on others it is a *clock*.

I'd like it to be a spinner in every case, but I don't know how to this with Cordova. Every solution I've found is for native Java app.

Comment: Please paste what you have tried. In cordova there is lot of plugins for date picker.

Comment: I didn't use a plugin, I used the HTML element <input type="time"> which is rendered by the browser on a computer, and I guess by the device on a mobile app. Gonna edit to clarify this.